# How to use sealed classes with generics in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

I can't find a solution to this problem

```
data class Data(val s: String)
sealed class Base<T>(val t: T, val f: Base<T>.() -> Unit)
class A(data: Data, f: A.() -> Unit) : Base<Data>(data, f)
```

Type mismatch.Required:`Base<Data>.() → Unit` Found: `A.() → Unit`

Please tell me what should be the correct usage

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with sealed classes, and nothing to do with generics. It is the same problem as the following:

```
fun fb(block: Number.() -> Unit) {
    BigDecimal.ONE.block()
}

fun fd(block: Int.() -> Unit) {
    fb(block)  // Error: required: Number.() -> Unit, found: Int.() -> Unit
}
```

As you can see from the above simplification of your problem, the reason for the error is that you can't pass a `Subclass.() -> Unit` block to something that expects a `Base.() -> Unit` block. If it were possible, then you would be able to call `fd` with a block that acts on an `Int` but `fb` passes it a `BigDecimal` instead. So you need to change your class A to:

```
class A(data: Data, f: Base<Data>.() -> Unit) : Base<Data>(data, f)
```